# Check output from popen

Tags: c, popen

I have a simple C program where I am trying to analyze the output of a bash command.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *rd;
    char buffer[100];
    rd=popen("dmesg | grep FTDI","r"); //bash command with pipe opened in reading mode
    if (rd == NULL)
    {
        puts("Unable to open process");
        return(1);
    }
    fread(buffer, 1, 100, rd); //will read 100 characters
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    pclose(rd);
}
```

Now I successfully print out the buffer. My goal is to analyze the output, and search for the string "ERROR" I am new to C, I think there is a function `strcmp` that can compare the output. Any recommendations?

Comment: The function you're looking for is `strstr()`. It will search for a substring in a string.

Comment: Note that the output read into `buffer` will not be null-terminated. Therefore `buffer` can't be used as a string. And you must always check for errors. Both `popen` as well as `fread` can fail. Or `fread` return a short read.

Comment: Use `fgets` rather than `fread`.  That will take care of SomeProgrammerDude's concern about null termination.  Although you may still have to worry about the possibility that the output contains two or more matching lines.

Answer (score 0):

you should use strstr() function:
the function gets two arguments, the string (buffer) and the substring ('ERROR').

```
if(strstr(buffer, "ERROR"))
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

this function look for the string "ERROR" in the string called 'buffer'